# Ear packing structure for jboss 7

Tags: jboss7.x, ear, build-tools

we are using J2EE 1.4, servlet version 1.4 and EJB version 2.1, when i deploy my ear file in jboss 7, which is build by using netbeans 6.9.1. I'm getting exception. Is there any specific deployment configuration for jboss 7, If so kindly help me to build a proper ear file which can be deployed in jboss 7. I there any build tool for it.

Comment: whAT IS the exception you are getting

Comment: 10:09:27,857 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."modulesettings.ear"."ModuleSettings-WebModule.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."modulesettings.ear"."ModuleSettings-WebModule.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "ModuleSettings-WebModule.war" of deployment "modulesettings.ear"

Comment: interesting enough, as in Netbeans7.1 I do not see the option of adding JBoss 7 as a server

Comment: module is developed in netbeans 6.9.1 and it has the Jboss 6 server, the module is working when i deploy it jboss 6. my question is why the same file is not working in jboss 7. is there any extra configuration required for it to deploy in jboss 7.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested in jb 6 and jb7, do not find any problem as per following logs:

09:26:15,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBA
S015876: Starting deployment of "mavenproject2-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
09:26:15,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-15) JB
AS015876: Starting deployment of "mavenproject2-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
09:26:15,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBA
S015876: Starting deployment of "mavenproject2-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
09:26:17,750 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS018210: Registe
ring web context: /mavenproject2-web
09:26:17,754 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015951: Admin co
nsole listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:26:17,756 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015874: JBoss AS
 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 27236ms - Started 202 of 283 services (80 serv
ices are passive or on-demand)
09:26:17,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018
559: Deployed "mavenproject2-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"

Please note that this ear has been created in netbeans7.1 with jboss 6 as target server , and all I did was to copy the ear in D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments

Comment: INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"TESTJB7.ear\".\"TESTJB7-ejb.jar\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"TESTJB7-ejb.jar\" of deployment \"TESTJB7.ear\""},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.TESTJB7.TESTJB7-ejb.NewSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.TESTJB7.TESTJB7-ejb.NewSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.TESTJB7.TESTJB7-ejb.NewSessionBean.
How to resolve the dependency.

Comment: wgere r u putting the ear ? need to place it in  D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments

Comment: ya i placed the ear in the above path only.

Comment: Hi do you know how resolve the dependency in jboss 7. in jboss 6 we place dependent jar in \default\lib folder. same way in jboss 7 where we have to place the common dependency jars. what needs to be done to make the bean class visible in war and ejb-jar. In jboss 6 if change the isolate property to false(<property name="isolated">false</property> ) the classes in other ejb jars are visible in all war and ejb-jar files in deploy folder. Is there any configuration in jboss 7 like jboss 6

Comment: try putting in D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\lib\ext

Comment: I have tried it, its not working.
https://community.jboss.org/message/731226#731226